# Java - Passing scanner into method then calling method

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to create a java program that take in a monetary amount $XX.xx and outputs the amount in change e-g number of quarters, dimes, nickels etc.

I am having trouble passing the scanner from the public class to the methods used in converting and then calling said methods in the main method.

Here's my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class moneyConverter{


double currentAmount = (int)(money *100.00);                            //variables

public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static double money = scan.nextDouble();


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        double money = 0.0;

        money.Dollar();
        money.Quarter();
         money.Dime();                                                  
        money.Nickel();
        money.Penny();


    }

    public static void Dollar(Scanner scan){                            

        double dollarAmount = scan.nextDouble() / 100.00;
        double currentAmount = dollarAmount % 100.00;

        System.out.println("Dollars: " +dollarAmount);

        return;

    }

    public static void Quarter(Scanner scan){

        double dollarAmount = scan.nextDouble() / 25.00;
        double currentAmount = dollarAmount % 25.00;

        System.out.println("Quarters: " +dollarAmount);

        return;

    }

    public static void Dime(Scanner scan){

        double dollarAmount = scan.nextDouble() / 10.00;
        double currentAmount = dollarAmount % 10.00;

        System.out.println("Dimes: " +dollarAmount);

        return;

    }

    public static void Nickel(Scanner scan){

        double dollarAmount = scan.nextDouble() / 5.00;
        double currentAmount = dollarAmount % 5.00;

        System.out.println("Nickels: " +dollarAmount);

        return;

    }

    public static void Penny(Scanner scan){

        double currentAmount = currentAmount;

        System.out.println("Pennies: " +currentAmount); 

        return;

    }
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: `I am having trouble passing the scanner` What does that mean? Compile time error? Runtime error?

Comment: What's with calling all the methods using `money` (which is a `double`) in main?

Comment: i was trying to have money as the object that is passed in from the scanner and call the methods to do the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

`money` is a `double`, which doesn't have the methods you are trying to call on it.

Just call the methods within the `moneyConverter` class by doing:

```
Dollar(scan);
Quarter(scan);
Dime(scan);
Nickel(scan);
Penny(scan);
```